# how to increase the array index in loop by +1 using swift

Tags: ios, arrays

```
leaders.append([Leaders(name: nameTF.text!, url: urlTF.text!)])
//I want to auto increase leaders[0] with +1 every time when it is in loop

for i in 0..<leaders.count{
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "\(leaders[0][0].name)", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler:{(_) -> Void in
            
            
    }))
}
```

Comment: It's pretty hard to tell what you're trying to do here without including more code (like what type `leaders` is). Is there a reason you can't just do `leaders[0] += 1`?

Comment: you need be more clear with your questions!

Comment: when i am keeping it loop only one value is looping i want like leaders[1],leaders[2] increase while looping it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean

```
for leader in leaders where !leader.isEmpty {
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: leader[0].name, style: .default, handler:{(_) -> Void in
            
            
    }))
}
```